# Show different class properties at different places

Tags: apex, class, apexrest

I am calling an GET API, where is am getting account details like
name, number, ext Id etc. For parsing the response, i created a class like below.

```
public class AccWrp {
    public String customer_no;
    public String customer_name;
    public String extId;
}
```

Now in one post call i need to send Account details(after upsert) with some extra fields,
like isActive, Email, Phone, Fax. 
I thought i will use same class for sending data back, as they are expecting same attributes in the JSON as above.
So i added other fields as well.

```
public class AccWrp {
    public String customer_no;
    public String customer_name;

    //used in post call
    public String email;
    public String phone_no;
    public String fax_no;
    public Boolean is_active;

}
```

But when i am using this AccWrp class instance in post call. Properties which are not used is going as null. like

> "customer_name": null, "customer_no" : null

Is there any way i can have only one class for parsing and for POST call without sending other properties as null.

Is there any way, i can have only one class?

Thanks,
Manohar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When making your JSON, pass in "true" as the second parameter to omit null values.

```
AccWrp a = new AccWrp();
// ...
String body = JSON.serialize(a, true);
// ...
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response. Passing true is omitting all the null values. Is there any way i can keep any specific value? 

can i send two properties in one response and other two in next response, even though its null. It should appear but properties should be specific to one API call. 
  
but i want to keep all my AccountWrp properties in one class. And send based on my API call.

Is it possible?

Comment: @Manohar No, it's all or none if you just use a class this way. You either need multiple classes, or you might consider just using a `Map<String, String>` instead, which you can serialize either way as you desire.